# Function for C++ struct

Tags: c++, function, struct

Usually we can define a variable for a C++ struct, as in

```
struct foo {
  int bar;
};
```

Can we also define functions for a struct? How would we use those functions?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Yes, a `struct` is identical to a `class` except for the default access level (member-wise and inheritance-wise). (and the extra meaning `class` carries when used with a template)

Every functionality supported by a class is consequently supported by a struct. You'd use methods the same as you'd use them for a class.

```
struct foo {
  int bar;
  foo() : bar(3) {}   //look, a constructor
  int getBar() 
  { 
    return bar; 
  }
};

foo f;
int y = f.getBar(); // y is 3
```

Comment: I don't see why one would use a getter where `bar` itself is publicly exposed?

Answer (score 56):

Structs can have functions just like classes. The only difference is that they are public by default:

```
struct A {
    void f() {}
};
```

Additionally, structs can also have constructors and destructors.

```
struct A {
    A() : x(5) {}
    ~A() {}

    private: int x;
};
```